# Creating table incrementally using loops in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

We have a large piece of complex SQL code that constantly falls over when run in HeidiSQL and MySQL WB. If we run the same code with smaller number of records it runs fine.
We are thinking that if we create a loop in an SP where the code is effectively split into 10 to 20 runs it may complete successfully. I think this may involve creating 10 to 20 tables which are union-ed into one table later on.

Tried running on smaller data sets, runs fine. Tried increasing the Server RAM and disk space. Tried adapting the code in many different ways.

I realise this may not be the ideal solution but have been asked to do it this way. If anyone could help me with the code, I would be grateful.

Below is code I built but doesn't work...

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;

 SET x = 100;

 WHILE x  <= 2000 DO

   DROP TABLE if EXISTS tablex; /* want to end up with table100-table2000 */

   CREATE TABLE tablex AS (
   SELECT t1.*
    FROM bigtables t1
    WHERE urn BETWEEN x AND x+101); /* select records where the URN is between 100 and 201 in 1st instance , 200 and 301 in second etc*/

    SET x=x+100;

 END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_mysql_while_loop();
```

20 tables

Comment: What is the error message?  I don't why this isn't running.

Comment: table name will always be tablex - mysql won't substitute the x with the value of x. Consider using dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I guess I want to know if the code will work in principle? Can I create table100 to table2000 based on where statement that effectively carves the bigtables into more manageable chunks.

Comment: Hi P.Salmon - is there a way of changing the table name so I get a table for each iteration of the loop at the end?

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of how to prepare and execute statements

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p;
 delimiter $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE p()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;

 SET x = 100;

 WHILE x  <= 300 DO

   set @sql= (select concat('DROP TABLE if EXISTS table',x)); 

   select @sql;
   prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
   execute sqlstmt;
   deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

   set @sql = (select concat('CREATE TABLE table',x,' AS 
   SELECT t1.*
    FROM users t1;'));

    select @sql;
   prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
   execute sqlstmt;
   deallocate prepare sqlstmt; 

     SET x=x+100;

 END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL p();
```

Comment: Thanks P, That's useful to have some code to start with. I'll have a play with it now :)

Comment: Hi P, This was really helpful in getting me going with this type of approach. Thanks so much for your help :-)